# Set Stripe customer id in parse cloud code

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, stripe-payments

I need help setting the first string parameter in Stripe's update customer function using Parse's cloud code. I tried to simply call the the parameter that I am sending in with the customer id but that does not seem to be even recognized by parse when I attempt to try it. Here is what I currently have:

Parse.Cloud.define("updatecustomer", function(request, response) {

var Stripe = require('stripe');
  Stripe.initialize('sk_test_#######');

```
  Stripe.Customers.update(
        request.params.customeruser //it does not seem to be picking up this line
  ,{ 
      card: request.params.card, 
      email: request.params.email,
      description: request.params.descriptionuser
  },{
      success: function(httpResponse) {
      response.success(httpResponse);
  },
      error: function(httpResponse) {
      response.error("Uh oh, something went wrong");
   }

 });
```

});

Answer (score 0):

are you getting request.params.customeruser in your request?

you can check that by logging it in the parse logs - 
    console.log(JSON.stringify(request.params));